# Is Using Python to MapReduce for Cassandra Dumb?

Tags: python, mongodb, cassandra, couchdb, nosql

Since Cassandra doesn't have MapReduce built in yet (I think it's coming in 0.7), is it dumb to try and MapReduce with my Python client or should I just use CouchDB or Mongo or something?

The application is stats collection, so I need to be able to sum values with grouping to increment counters. I'm not, but pretend I'm making Google analytics so I want to keep track of which browsers appear, which pages they went to, and visits vs. pageviews.

I would just atomically update my counters on write, but Cassandra isn't very good at counters either.

May Cassandra just isn't the right choice for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cassandra supports map reduce since version 0.6. (Current stable release is 0.5.1, but go ahead and try the new map reduce functionality in 0.6.0-beta3) To get started I recommend to take a look at the word count map reduce example in 'contrib/word_count'.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB has update-in-place, so MongoDB should be very good with counters. http://blog.mongodb.org/post/171353301/using-mongodb-for-real-time-analytics

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer, sorry I can't pick two, the other one was more specifically an answer to my issue with Cassandra.